# Aperiodicity and convergence in Markov chains

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

My question is fairly simple - we know that if a Markov chain is irreducible and all states are aperiodic, the chain converges to equilibrium. However, if we have one state which is not aperiodic, is that enough to say that the chain does not converge to equilibrium?

For example, consider the chain (with state space {1,2,3,4}) with the following probability matrix: $$ \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
0.3 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
We can see right away that the first state (call it {1}) has period 2. Is this enough to say that the chain does not converge to equilibrium?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $